# How does Kotlin coroutine Flow .map function know how to apply transformation

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-coroutines, transformation, kotlin-stateflow

I have this "state" object:

```
data class StudentState(
   val students: List<Student> = emptyList()
)
```

In my ViewModel I have val called `studentState` which I am instantiating this way:

```
val studentState: StateFlow<StudentState> =
   studentRepository.getStudents().map {
      StudentState(it)
   } .stateIn(
         scope = viewModelScope,
         started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(TIMEOUT_MILLIS),
         initialValue = StudentState()
      )
```

This code works, but my question is how does the `.map` function know which value in the `StudentState` to apply the flow from the repository?
What if I want to hold another list in my `StudentState` for example:

```
data class StudentState(
   val students: List<Student> = emptyList()
   val studentClasses: List<StudentClasses> = emptyList()
)
```

If I want to get populate it in the viewmodel from another call tot he repository how would I do it?

I am trying to understand how the .map function works in details in the above example.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question, but it doesn't seem related to `map()` or to flows in general. `StudentState(it)` means we call a constructor of `StudentState`, passing a single `it` argument - as simple as that, no magic involved. If we have two optional parameters and we pass a single one, it will assume this is the first param.

Comment: You may be right and I am overthinking this. So the .map simply says take the result of the original function and pass it tot he lambda function as it and I need to put the logic int he lambda function to do whatever I need which is then returned as StateFlow? Do I have it right? I thought there was more to .map than that but I guess the power is in the simplicity?